# Как добавить данные в словарь с новым ключом?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

Есть словарь. В него пытаюсь добавить примерно похожие данные, но с разными ключами:

```
d = {}
d['category', 'key:911', 'title:lk'] = {'#41': {'title': 'абетка', 'description': 'нет описания', 'price': '100'}}
d['category', 'key:911', 'title:lk'] = {'#42': {'title': 'абетка', 'description': 'нет описания', 'price': '100'}}
```

В первой строке у меня в качестве ключа `#41`, в другой строке ключ на единицу больше, чем предыдущий, а именно `#42`.

Как я могу добавить данные, чтобы после указания `#41` в словаре, я мог получить `{'title': 'абетка', 'description': 'нет описания', 'price': '100'}}` и при указании `#42` уже другие данные,  Примечание: данные были написаны в качестве примера, чтобы решить текущую проблему.

При попытке вывести словарь c необходимыми данными с помощью кода:

```
products_keys = d['category', 'key:911', 'title:lk']
print(products_keys)
```

Получаю только:

```
{'#42': {'title': 'абетка', 'description': 'нет описания', 'price': '100'}}
```

Comment: Ключ словаря - уникален. Поэтому во второй строке вы __перезаписываете__ значение по ключу: 'category', 'key:911', 'title:lk'

Comment: `'category', 'key:911', 'title:lk'` это у меня отдельный ключ категории :) И в эту категорию мне нужно добавить товар )

Comment: Словарю все равно что для вас значит ключ  С тем же успехом можно сделать: d[1] = 10; d[1] = 11; и потом удивляться куда делась десятка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по уточняющему вопросу в комментариях, вам может лучше подойти такое решение:

```
category = 'category', 'key:911', 'title:lk'

d = {}               # словарь в который будут применены изменения
d[category] = {}
d[category]['#41'] = {'title': 'абетка', 'description': 'нет описания', 'price': '100'}
d[category]['#42'] = {'title': 'абетка', 'description': 'нет описания', 'price': '100'}
```

Comment: Это действительно проще для запоминания и использования.

Answer (score 1):

В данной строке `d['category', 'key:911', 'title:lk']` вы в словарь `d` записываете ключ `['category', 'key:911', 'title:lk']`, следовательно если вы будете в этот ключ добавлять значения ключа, то сохранится последний из записанных значений в ключе. Как пример, вы можете записать пустой список в значение ключа и добавлять в список значения.

```
d = {}

d['category', 'key:911', 'title:lk'] = []

d['category', 'key:911', 'title:lk'].append({'#41': {'title': 'абетка', 'description': 'нет описания', 'price': '100'}})

d['category', 'key:911', 'title:lk'].append({'#40': {'title': 'абетка', 'description': 'нет описания', 'price': '100'}})

for i in d['category', 'key:911', 'title:lk']:
    print(i)
```

Можно через словарь:

```
d = {}

d['category', 'key:911', 'title:lk'] = {}

d['category', 'key:911', 'title:lk'].update([('#41', {'title': 'абетка', 'description': 'нет описания', 'price': '100'})])

d['category', 'key:911', 'title:lk'].update([('#40', {'title': 'абетка', 'description': 'нет описания', 'price': '100'})])

print(d['category', 'key:911', 'title:lk']['#40'])
```

Comment: А можно получить `{'title': 'абетка', 'description': 'нет описания', 'price': '100'}`, одной строкой кода указав где-либо `#41`?

Comment: @MaximChyorny да, можно, я обновил ответ.

Comment: Большое спасибо!